# Laravel - link to a file saved in storage folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

When we do something like this:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

How do you make a link to that file in a view? Something like this:

```
<a href="path_to_file.txt">Download File</a>
```

there are so many things in documentation and yet not even one example how to create a link to that file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

According to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#retrieving-files), You can get the URL to the file like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::url('file1.jpg');
```

> Remember, if you are using the local driver, all files that should be
>   publicly accessible should be placed in the `storage/app/public`
>   directory. Furthermore, you should create a symbolic link at
>   `public/storage` which points to the `storage/app/public` directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i will test this now

Answer (score 9):

Try this command on your terminal : **php artisan storage:link**, then laravel storage become public access.

```
<a href="{{url('/')}}/{{ Storage::disk('local')->url('file.txt')}}">Download File</a>
```

Comment: Using this, everyone with this link is able to see the file. What if only authenticated users should be able to see and download the file??

Comment: then you put the link behind the auth middleware

Answer (score 2):

Scenario--(working from a fresh Laravel 5.6 project install for reference): 
With the existing default paths being /public and /storage/app/public and you want to physically store your logo.png image in the /storage folder and render it on your Welcome page, the process would go something like this:

1. In your terminal, navigate to your Laravel project folder.
2. Run command `php artisan storage:link`
3. Now create the folder /images in your /storage/app/public folder which gives you /storage/app/public/images.
4. Look in your /public folder and you will see the (shortcut) subfolders /storage/images
5. Copy a test image named logo.png into the /storage/app/public/images folder.
6. In your project's welcome.blade.php under /resources/views paste the 
      following code over the existing code:

   ```
   <div class="content">
       <div class="title m-b-md">
           Laravel
           <div>
               <a href="/">
                 <img src="{{url('/storage/images/logo.png')}}" alt="Logo Image"/>
               </a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
7. Save and open your project in your browser and you should see the logo image.

Having said all of that, later on you need a pdf folder to store uploaded pdf 
files. Easy, just create a new folder in /storage/app/public called /pdf and 
automatically the shortcut will appear in the /public folder. It is a once and "for all" solution.

Comment: I do the same thing but not working for me. storage shortcut folder is created but inside the storage folder is not created. 

like :- storage\app\public