# Laravel symbolic link to storage and show the pictures

Tags: php, laravel

In storage i have /projects/(nameofproject - not always the same)/header.jpg and also have /projects/(nameofproject - not always the same)/home.png.

How can i show them in my view?

I explain it a bit more.
In the past, i have projects on /public/assets/img/projects and now i do it dynamically.

My function to create the new projects and save the images is this:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
        {
        $project = new Project();
        $project->slug = $request->input("slug");
        $project->position = $request->input("position");
        $project->public = $request->input("public");
        $project->pathheader = $request->file('pathheader');
        $project->pathhome = $request->file('pathhome');
        \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
        \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.png');
        \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathhome,'home.png');
        $project->save();
        return redirect('/admin/projects');

        }
```

The images of the projects i do in the past i show it with this: (I pass to the view the variable $project)

```
<p class="lead"><img src="/assets/img/projects/{{$project->slug}}/header.jpg" width="50%" >Header</p>
<p class="lead"><img src="/assets/img/projects/{{$project->slug}}/home.jpg" width="50%">Home</p>
```

How to show the images of the storage folder?

**EDIT**

filesystems.php code:

```
 'projects' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path() . '/projects',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

View looking like this now:

```
@if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
<img src="{{ asset('storage/projects/'.$project-
>slug.'/header.jpg') }}" width="50%" >
@else
<p class="lead"><img src="/assets/img/projects/{{$project-
>slug}}/header.jpg" width="50%" >Header</p>
@endif
```

I make:

> php artisan storage:link

url of image: http://url.loc/storage/projects/hola-que-tal/header.jpg (not show it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936332/laravel-link-to-a-file-saved-in-storage-folder

Comment: @Bas "Remember, if you are using the local driver, all files that should be publicly accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public directory. Furthermore, you should create a symbolic link at public/storage which points to the storage/app/public directory." Not in storage/app/public, they are in /storage/projects/$foldername(variable)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use the [public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk). If you ran the `php artisan storage:link` command you can use the following code:

```
\Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
\Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs($project->slug, $project->pathheader, 'header.png');
\Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs($project->slug, $project->pathhome, 'home.png');
```

And your HTML:

```
<p class="lead"><img src="{{ asset('storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/header.jpg') }}" width="50%" >Header</p>
<p class="lead"><img ssrc="{{ asset('storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.jpg') }} width="50%">Home</p>
```

An example for the config in `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/projects'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Of course you can edit your `projects` disk so that it has the correct `root`. But I'm not sure how your config looks for the `projects` disk.

Comment: Hi @Dees040 i can't use the public disk, this is a problem. i'm trying to do something maybe you can help me. I edit the bottom of the question. If you know how to make a chat, do it if you want :)

Comment: You send a `/{{$project->slug}}` literally as a string. Should be this: `Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug)`. But then you check if the folder exists. Maybe you also need to add the file name as well? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Correct. I have to pass $project->slug. I check if the folder with the $project-slug exist and then i try to render the picture. not working for now.

Comment: Yes, now enter to the if, but don't render the picture so the route is wrong i think. It's a bit confusing. With the route: `Route::get('/project/{slug}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getProjectImage', 'as' => 'admin.project.image']);`i pass only the slug, maybe it's wrong, but in my mind no. I think i should pass the slug. My function look now a bit different. I update the question.

Comment: Maybe you try and use the solution in my answer. You only need to change the config and then you can use it like you had it first with the `asset()` function.

Comment: I will try it now. Let's see. I have the disk projects like this: 'projects' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path() . '/projects',], 
should put visibility public? i think yes. But url?

Comment: question edited. I think maybe i need change filesystem or maybe the command is wrong cause i not use the default disk.