# Laravel - Display preview of file stored in Storage directory

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have to upload some files for each users, and the files should not be accessible publicly.

When a user a created, I'm creating a folder in storage directory using-

```
Storage::makeDirectory($user->ref_id);
```

Now I've a files table, which stores the file details. Here is the code for uploading file and saving the path to the database.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'required|mimetypes:image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf',
]);
$user = Auth::user();
$filename = time() . '.' . $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = $request->file('file')->storeAs($user->ref_id, $filename);

$user->files()->create(['file_name' => $path]);
```

The file is being stored successfully. Now when a user logs in, I want to display a preview of that file in the view.

Any help, how can I do that??

Comment: run ```php artisan storage:link```

Comment: Still not able to access the files, the file is currently being stored in storage/app/{user->ref_id} folder

Comment: Show how you are accessing the files

Comment: <embed name="plugin" src="{{asset($file->file_name)}}" type="application/pdf">, the src is being replace with [{{Storage::get($file->file_name)}}], [{{Storage::url($file->file_name)}}], [{{storage_path($file->file_name)}}], [{{asset('app/'.$file->file_name)}}] etc..

Comment: try ```{{asset('app/public/'.$file->file_name)}}```

Comment: Already tried and not working, the output of this is - http://localhost/rupyz/public/app/public/STPF1807001/1532075487.pdf

Comment: remove the first public then try again

Comment: Still not working. It is accessible to the view??

Comment: yess you can directy access it in view

Comment: But, It is still not accessible for me, I hard coded this - 'http://localhost/rupyz/storage/app/STPF1807001/1532075487.pdf' and the files is being accessed.

Comment: you need to use `file_get_content($file_path)`, use the result in `src`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you serve a file from a controller. Instead of returning a view you return the file like this. In case of an image you can't echo it directly to the view unless you base64 encode it (which increases the filesize).

```
return response()
        ->download($file_path, "file_name",
            [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
            ]);
```

Make a function in your controller containing the code above and some logic to retrieve the right file path and make a route for it.
After you've done that you can (for example) add in your view

```
<img src="{{route('ROUTE_NAME')}}">
```

You'll have to fill in all the variables yourself ofcourse.

Using this method the files will always stay private and will only be echoed once you allowed the user access. Note that this WILL use more recourses as you let PHP handle serving the file instead of apache. Hope this helps!

Comment: What will be the file_path??

Comment: tries with storage_path('app/' . $folder . '/' . $name);, but it's showing no preview. Accessing link directly the file starts downloading with no extension.

Comment: `Content-Type` contains the Mimetype of a file, when it's octet-stream it'll initiate a download. You can find out the actual mime type by calling `mime_content_type($file_path)` .

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41322072/6792282

I used this in my code and preview is working fine for pdf files..

```
<embed name="plugin" src="{{url('/')}}/{{ Storage::disk('local')->url($file->file_name)}}" type="application/pdf">
```